# Multiplying two dataframes returns NaN and wrong shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to multiply two data frames to get a new one. All variables in both data frames are integers, and indexes in both are reset and go from 0:n.
These are my data

**df1**

> ```
>    11   12   13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
> 0  54   87   77  53  30  21   0   0   0   0
> 1  60  146  171  66  36  34   0   0   0   0
> 2  49   76   87  57  34  35   0   0   0   0
> 3  49   76   77  53  30  21   0   0   0   0
> ```

**df2**

> ```
>     A5   A6   A7   A8 
> 0  200  300  400  500 
> 1  201  301  401  501 
> 2  202  302  402  502 
> 3  203  303  403  503
> ```

If I use `.mul` method, all results in the data frame are NaN and the shape is all wrong (no matter which axis I use).

`df2.mul(df1)`

**Result**

> ```
>    11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  A5  A6  A7  A8
> 0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
> 1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
> 2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
> 3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
> ```

Expected result is a table like this

> ```
>    11    12      13      14      15      16  17  18  19  20
> 72900 129600  140000  79700   45400   38900   0   0   0   0
> 73112 129985  140412  79929   45530   39011   0   0   0   0
> 73324 130370  140824  80158   45660   39122   0   0   0   0
> 73536 130755  141236  80387   45790   39233   0   0   0   0
> ```

If I multiply df1 or df2 with scalar (like `df1 * 2`) the results are ok.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you add what your expected output is to the question?

Comment: The dataframes have different shapes, so pandas can't guess how you want to multiply them. Please share the expected output

Comment: You column names are different, the expected results is not understanble. If it were multiplication, I would expect e.g. col 11 to give 3 different results and rows 2 & 3 the same result.

Comment: `mul` is element-wise multiplication but you seem to be doing the matrix multiplication.  Also, you can only multiply df2 * df1 not df1 * df2 (order matters in matrix multiplication).  Try renaming the columns to align the both dataframes then `df2.dot(df1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't return the columns with zeros but this will return the two multiplied together. Is this what you are looking for?

```
df1.drop(columns=df1.columns[len(df2.columns):]).mul(df2)
```

Comment: No, I made a mistake when reproducing an example (I switched df1 and df2). Emma's comment helped. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So, `.mul` is for element wise multiplication, but I wanted to do matrix multiplication, so `.dot` was needed. The solution is:

```
df1.set_index(df2.columns, inplace = True)
df2.dot(df1)
```